# Group array to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello apologies if this has been asked before but I can't search for the right term to find something useful.

Suppose if I had an array of

```
[
 "0.001234", "2021-07-14 08:24:30"
 "0.001245", "2021-07-14 01:04:24"
 // etc etc ...
]
```

how would I change this to an object like so?

```
{
 0: ["0.001234", "2021-07-14 08:24:30"]
 1: ["0.001245", "2021-07-14 01:04:24"]
 // etc etc ...
}
```

Comment: You should just have a nested array. Changing the array to an object makes no sense.

Comment: I'm trying to return a json response on an api endpoint

Comment: If your concern is just simply post the array, you can try `JSON.stringify(array)` or if you wish to do more, please follow up the anwser given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - just noticed the format of your data - map reduce may not work for you, but still a similar principle:

```
let objForm = {}
for (let idx=0; idx<arrayForm.length; idx+=2) {
  objForm[idx/2] = [ arrayForm[idx], arrayForm[idx+1] ]
}
```

Old answer:

You can use a `reduce` pattern.

```
let arrayForm = ["one", "two"]
let objForm = arrayForm.reduce((acc, val, idx) => ({
  ...acc,
  [idx]: val
}), {})
console.log(objForm) // { 0: "one", 1: "two" }
```

The `reduce` method gets the accumulated value, the current value and the array index. In this case we are using the *spread* operator to add the next value to the object.

Note that the `(` before the object definition is needed, so that JS doesn't confuse it with a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new object and then iterate over the array in element pairs and add them as a new array to the object.

```js
const arr = [
 '0.001234', '2021-07-14 08:24:30',
 '0.001245', '2021-07-14 01:04:24'
];

const obj = {};

for (let i = 0;  i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  obj[i / 2] = [ arr[i], arr[i + 1] ];
}

console.log(obj);
```